# Aplicacion se cierra al tratar de mandar a una clase dependiendo su rango

Tags: mysql, android, android-studio, base-de-datos, android-volley

Tengo una aplicación de android que esta conectada a una base de datos por php, lo tengo con un sistema de logueo que funciona al 100%, pero lo que quiero es que se conecte a la base de datos y verifique los id por ejemplo: 1.- Se loguea un empleado, el empleado esta registrado en la base de datos con la id "1" entonces pasa a la clase "empleado.class" 2.- Se loguea un gerente, el gerente está registrado en la base de datos con la id "2" entonces pasará a la clase "gerente.class"

Puse en el codigo algo como esto:

```
        public void run(){
        String valor = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario");
        String id2=getIntent().getStringExtra("Id");//En una clase anterior puse que sacara de la base dato el id y lo guardase aquí
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("matricula", valor);
        if(id2.equals("1") || id2.equals("2"))//Intento de hacer la comparación, si la id es igual a "1" o "2" los lleve a la clase Camaraqr {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Segundo.this, Camaraqr.class);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else/* Si es otrodiferente que los lleve a la clase maestro*/{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Segundo.this, maestros.class);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Sin embargo, cuando abro la aplicación y me logueo se cierra automaticamente, no sé que hice mal, aquí el cómo verifico cual es la id de la persona que entra al login

```
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Idx.setText(jsonObject.getString("TipoRegistrado_Id_Registrado"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error de conexion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    );
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

2020-06-27 16:43:22.478 7712-7712/? I/xample.tallero: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

2020-06-27 16:43:22.532 7712-7723/? E/xample.tallero: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer
2020-06-27 16:43:22.656 7712-7712/? I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2020-06-27 16:43:22.801 7712-7743/? I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : cf57c9c, I1cb5c4d1cc
Build Date                       : 09/23/18
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
Local Branch                     :
Remote Branch                    :
Remote Branch                    :
Reconstruct Branch               :
2020-06-27 16:43:22.801 7712-7743/? I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
2020-06-27 16:43:22.806 7712-7743/? I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2020-06-27 16:43:22.810 7712-7743/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-06-27 16:43:22.810 7712-7743/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-06-27 16:43:22.811 7712-7743/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-06-27 16:43:22.811 7712-7743/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-06-27 16:43:25.249 7712-7712/com.example.tallerof D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-06-27 16:43:25.253 7712-7712/com.example.tallerof E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tallerof, PID: 7712
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.example.tallerof.Segundo$1.run(Segundo.java:30)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
2020-06-27 16:43:30.697 7712-7740/com.example.tallerof I/xample.tallero: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=0 is saved saved_to_disk=0 resolve_classes_delay=8000

Comment: Hola, decir se cierra tiene infinidad de causas,revisa el LogCat y agrega en tu pregunta que mensaje de error se muestra.

Comment: Listo, lo he añadido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
> java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
> at com.example.tallerof.Segundo$1.run(Segundo.java:30)

indica que estas tratando de llamar el mètodo equals() en una instancia con valor null, esto ocurre dentro del mètodo run() donde tratas de obtener el valor que recibes mediante un bundle, aquì el valor definitivamente serà null ya que debes recordar que **el `bundle` que recibes mediante un `Intent` debe ser obtenido dentro del mètodo `onCreate()` de tu `Activity`**:

```
//Define variables de clase
private String valor;
private String id2;
...
...
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
 
        //obtiene valores pero valida en caso de tener valores null.
         valor = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario")!= null?getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario"):"";
         id2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Id")!=null?getIntent().getStringExtra("Id"):"";


   }

...
...
        public void run(){
        //String valor = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario");
        //String id2=getIntent().getStringExtra("Id");//En una clase anterior puse que sacara de la base dato el id y lo guardase aquí
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("matricula", valor);
        if(id2.equals("1") || id2.equals("2"))//Intento de hacer la comparación, si la id es igual a "1" o "2" los lleve a la clase Camaraqr {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Segundo.this, Camaraqr.class);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else/* Si es otrodiferente que los lleve a la clase maestro*/{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Segundo.this, maestros.class);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```